# How do function objects affect overload resolution?

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution, function-object

Are function objects treated differently from regular functions during overload resolution? If so, how?

I have run into the following case where replacing a function with an equivalently-callable function object changed the meaning of the code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N
{
    enum E { A, B };

    void bar(E mode) { std::cout << "N::bar\n"; }
}

template <typename... Args>
void bar(Args&&... args) { std::cout << "global bar\n"; }

int main()
{
    bar(N::A);
}
```

Here the output is "N::bar". So far, so good: N::bar is being found by ADL, both N::bar and the global bar are exact matches, and N::bar is preferred because it's not a template.

But if I change the global bar to be a function object, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N
{
    enum E { A, B };

    void bar(E mode) { std::cout << "N::bar\n"; }
}

struct S
{
    template <typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args&&... args) { std::cout << "global bar\n"; }
};
S bar;

int main()
{
    bar(N::A);
}
```

The output is now "global bar". Why the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The important bit here is that ADL only kicks in if lookup determines that the name *is* a function in the function call. In the second case, `bar` is found to be an *object* and not a function, so the expression `bar(N::A)` is not a function call, but the application of `operator()` to the object `bar`. Because it is not a function call, ADL does not kick in and `N::bar` is not considered.

> 3.4.1/3
>
> The lookup for an unqualified name used as the postfix-expression of a function call is described in 3.4.2. [ Note: For purposes of determining (during parsing) whether an expression is a postfix-expression for a func- tion call, the usual name lookup rules apply. The rules in 3.4.2 *[ADL]* have no effect on the syntactic interpretation of an expression.

Another way to look at it is to notice that ADL will add new functions to the *set of overloaded functions*, but in the second example there is no such set: lookup finds an object and a member of the object is called.

Comment: I don't think that the note at 3.4.1/3 is relevant, because `bar` *is* the postfix-expression in a function call expression (not having a function as operand, but eventually calling one!). The note says that 3.4.2 does not change the syntactic meaning of "x(y)" - if it is a function call, it stays a function call disregarding of what 3.4.2 decides to do.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Regular lookup will find that `bar` is an object, and being an object `bar(x)` represents the application of `operator()` to that instance. While the application of the operator is a function call, it is a *member-function* call, and thus ADL does not apply.

Comment: @david you are confusing all the different entities here

Answer (score 4):

See 3.4.2p3, which says

> Let X be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) and let Y be the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup (defined as follows). If X contains
>
> - ...
> - a declaration that is neither a function or a function template
>
> then Y is empty.

If there would not be such a rule, you are right: ADL would add your other function to the overload set. In fact, 13.3.1.1p1 relies on this: It has two branches; one for function call expressions where the operand denotes a class object, and another one where the operand denotes one or more functions or function templates.

Comment: +1, after reviewing that part of the standard, the quote you provide is the reason for the note I quoted.

Comment: @david you are misunderstanding it